# Printing Data from Servlet to browser asynchronously

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, println

I'm trying to send data to a web page sequentially, I do know how HTML works, and that the most likely answer to this would be ajax, but the requirement is that this work with only java and html. A page usually compiles in its container and then sends the output to browser as the response, I'd like to do something like the following, without using AJAX.

This must send the date and print it back to the browser without loading all 5 dates ... For example, a new date must appear on the web page every 5 seconds, and not all together in 25 seconds.

Any ideas?

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        out.println("<p>#" + i + " " + new Date() + "</p>");
        out.flush();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about hiding those `<p>`s and then show it via javascript. otherwise I don't think there's any simple solution here. Servlets don't use magic ;) they rely on the unidirectionality of HTML, but you knew that.

Comment: Can't hide them, I have to print the data out as it is generated. Without the use of ajax or javascript .... but as far as I know this can not be done with HTML alone....

Comment: HTML is a document description language. Everything that makes it feel alive is javascript. HTML5 is pushing against that, bit you still need javascript to achieve important things.
Why aren't you allowed to use AJAX or JS?

Comment: The name right name is Comet ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) )
Check this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html

Comment: `Comet is an umbrella term, encompassing multiple techniques for achieving this interaction. All these methods **rely on features included by default in browsers, such as JavaScript**, rather than on non-default plugins.` Comet is a way to do that, but don't know if it really fits.

Comment: @Zhedar, My boss likes things like this. Pushing on things that aren't supposed to work and getting them to work.

Comment: @TizianoPiccardi, I am looking into that. It appears that it might work. Will respond back here with my findings.

Comment: Well, that look's different.
I would recommend you to look into atmosphere ( https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere ), too. It also supports Comet along with WebSockets, Long-Polling, Streaming, ServerSentEvents, etc. as fallbacks.

Comment: Got it working... It's now printing it directly to the browser stream... quite a simple solution actually.

Comment: OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(osr);

Comment: It was actually my work proxy that caching even after I flushed the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

The `OutputStream` was printing into the browser directly, but as I have a proxy at work the proxy was caching the data as it was being printed out, bypassing the proxy fixed this issue. The out stream then has no caching in between it and the browser which allows it to print directly into the browser's output.

With this example you can see as the data gets printed into the browser window line by line, it does not wait the full 25 seconds before displaying the data.

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                       IOException {
    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    response.setHeader("CacheControl", "no-cache");
    //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

```
OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(osr);

br.append("<html>");
br.append("<head><title>Load</title></head>");
br.append("<body>");
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    br.append("<div>#" + i + " " + new Date() + "</div>");
    br.flush();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot sleep");
    }
}
br.append("</body></html>");

br.close();
```

}